# AFNetworking check progress

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I'm using the AFNetworking framework to download files and write them to the local file system.

But since the files can be quite big I want to add a `UIProgressView`, but I can't seem to find any method that gets updated with the progress.

I see people talking about setProgressBlock, but I can't find any information about this in the docs: http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html

Is there a method that does this? I'm just using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to download the files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `setDownloadProgressBlock` method is part of `AFURLConnectionOperation`, from which `AFHTTPRequestOperation` inherits - that's why you don't see it in the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` documentation. The documentation you're after is here:

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html

Comment: The given URL doesn't work. [This](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html) is the url.

Comment: Thanks, they have changed their documentation links since I posted (Cocoadocs didn't exist at the time). I have amended the answer.

Answer (score 15):

refer a following code. this is a some file download using a AFNetworking Code.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blahblah.com/blahblah.mp3"]];
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blahblah.mp3"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
{
    myProgressView.progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
}];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"downloadComplete!");
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: Note: the variable bytesRead is an NSUInteger. Thanks!